# Windows Storage Server... Just a single Administrator session?

Tags: windows, storage, windows-storage-server

I have a server with `"Windows Storage Server 2008 R2 Standard"` operating system.

My problem is that I cannot access the server with `Administrator` account with two users at the same time... Just one can operate. Can you help me?

Comment: What for? You can change the GPO, make another Administrator user, but at the end - why the heck do you think you need more than one administrator logged onto a storage server at the same time? Want to make sure they fight each other?

Comment: In my unit there are tree people that manage a pool of server and it is possible that two people need to be logged in in the same time for different purpose. In the other servers it is possible do it...

Comment: Then be happy that this is not possible. First, they should be competnt enough to know how to change thep olicy, but second - the rule should be only one admin works on a server AT THE SAME TIME. What you do now is a recipe for a disaster when two admins make non-compatible changes.

Comment: @TomTom wrote: Then be happy that this is not possible. 

It is not possible? Have you ever saw this: http://goo.gl/VdJ4K ?
I know that it is possible. If it is a wrong mode it is another question...

Comment: It is possible if someone is smart enough to know noow to create a second administrator account or set the group policy to allow more than one sesion per user - that is all admin basics. So, we now know syour people dont know the basics, but then yo uare happy to have multiple non-coordinated admins on one machine? OUCH. I am more than happy to have only ONE admin on a machine at a given time - makes sure my machines work. No 2 people making competitive administration.

Comment: I understand. Microsoft has accustomed us wrong for years.
PS. I do not have time to explain why I need the double session but this is a matter of backward compatibility. Thanks for the support, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the response in another user question:
[Does Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard only support 1 connected remote administrator?](https://serverfault.com/questions/342758/does-windows-server-2008-r2-standard-only-support-1-connected-remote-administrat)

> Check the Group Policy for "Restrict each user to a single session setting"

To run Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration from the Start menu:
Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, point to Remote Desktop Services, and then click Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.